# Convert input decimal separator between different languages?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, internationalization, gsp

I have a for on a website running in German. In this for you can enter prices. 
I German you will enter a price like this:

```
49,95
```

which means 49 of the currency and 95 cents. The separator here in German is a comma. My default language of the website is English. so I have to right the above as:

```
49.95
```

to be a valid English price notation meaning 49 currency and 95 cents.

**How do I convert the German user input (from the Grails GSP) of the price such that it is stored in the correct English format?**

Comment: em, like `price.replaceFirst(',', '.')`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html